# PHP parameter variable vs reference

Tags: php

What is the difference between in php function

- A parameter passage by **variable**
- A parameter pass by **reference**?

Comment: I think you mean by `value` not by `variable`. This is also covered all over the place. At least try to look first.

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**A parameter passage by value** - value of a variable is passed.

```
$b = 1;
function a($c) {
   $c = 2; // modifying this doesn't change the value of $b, since only the value was passed to $c.
}

a($b);
echo $b; // still outputs 1
```

**A parameter pass by reference?** - a pointer to a variable is passed.

```
$b = 1;
function a($c) {
   $c = 2; // modifying this also changes the value of $b, since variable $c points to it
}

a($b);
echo $b; // outputs 2 now after calling a();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand it is from an example:

```
function foo($a) {
  $a = 123;
  echo "Value in function: " . $a;
}
function bar(&$a) {
  $a = 123;
  echo "Value in function: " . $a;
}

$var = 555;
foo($var);
echo "After foo: " . $var;
bar($var);
echo "After bar: " . $var;
```

Basically you will change the value pointed by the reference, changing it also out of the function scope, while in a normal by-value when the function is finished the changes made to the variable will be lost. Here is an official PHP manual [link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), with more examples.